# Passing the state from a Redux Slice to the Component is giving me undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm doing this in other components very similarly, except this one takes a parameter of title_id. I am getting my data to fetch when I check the Redux DevTool and I console logged the payload from the mediaSlice too, but the useSelector in my Component is bringing nothing in and not updating my state. Can you help me figure out what exactly is it that I am messing up on so my selector can send the payload to my Component's state?

I made comments/questions in my code below where I think my problem areas are.

Here is my mediaSlice.js

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL
const SINGLE_MEDIA_API = `${BASE_URL}/titlestest`

const initialState = {
  media:[],
  status: 'idle', 
  error:null
}

export const fetchSingleMediaTitle = createAsyncThunk(
  'medias/fetchSingleMediaTitle', 
  async (mediaId) => { // <-- would this be where I declare the param key I am using?
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        SINGLE_MEDIA_API,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-API-KEY': KEY,
          },
          params: {
            titleId: mediaId,
          }
        }
      )

      return response.data.Item;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('API call error:', error.message);
    }
  }
)

const mediaSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'medias',
  initialState,
  reducers:{},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchSingleMediaTitle.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'loading'
      })
      .addCase(fetchSingleMediaTitle.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'succeeded'
        const loadedMedia = action.payload
        state.media = loadedMedia
              console.log("loadedMedia: ", loadedMedia); // this is successfully printing the data object
      })
      .addCase(fetchSingleMediaTitle.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'failed'
        state.error = action.error.message
      })
  }
})

// SELECTORS
export const selectSingleMedia = (state, mediaId) => state.media.media.find(item => item.title_id === mediaId); //this is where I am suspecting the problem is in

export const getMediaStatus = (state) => state.media.status;
export const getMediaError = (state) => state.media.error;

export default mediaSlice.reducer
```

And my Component. Reduced for brevity

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, Fragment } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getMediaError, getMediaStatus, selectSingleMedia, fetchSingleMediaTitle } from '../../features/medias/mediaSlice'
import { useParams, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const SingleMediaTitle = () => {
  //STATES
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); 

  const {mediaId} = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const media = useSelector((state, mediaId) => selectSingleMedia(state, mediaId)) //This is a suspect line too
  const mediaStatus = useSelector(getMediaStatus)
  const error = useSelector(getMediaError)
    
  useEffect(() => { 
    if (mediaStatus === 'idle') {
      dispatch(fetchSingleMediaTitle(mediaId))
    }
    setData(media);
    console.log("media: ", media); // This is undefined

  }, [mediaId, media, mediaStatus, dispatch])


  let content;

  if (mediaStatus === 'loading') {
    content = <Box className="loading">
                <Typography variant="subtitle2">Loading ..</Typography>
              </Box>
  } else if (mediaStatus === 'succeeded') {
    content = <Box>
                {media.content_source} //Though redux succeeded, this is not displaying 
              <Box/>  
  } else if (mediaStatus === 'failed') {
    content = <Box className="loading">
                <Typography variant="subtitle2">{error}</Typography>
              </Box>
  } 

  return (
    <Box sx={{p:3, pt:9}}> {content} </Box>      
  )
}

export default SingleMediaTitle
```

I really appreciate your help. Being the only front end dev in house is tough lol

Answer (score 0):

I can spot 2 things that can cause the problem:

###### 1) Your selectors

Since `useSelector` will get the entire state, you have to dig into your slice first and then deeper into the `media` data. Since the name of slice is `medias` this should be the first one. According to this your selectors should be:

```
// SELECTORS
export const selectSingleMedia = (state, mediaId) => state.medias.media.find(item => item.title_id === mediaId);

export const getMediaStatus = (state) => state.medias.media.status;
export const getMediaError = (state) => state.medias.media.error;
```

###### 2) The single media selector

```
  const {mediaId} = useParams();
  const media = useSelector((state, mediaId) => selectSingleMedia(state, mediaId))
```

Since `mediaId` exists in the scope of the selector you should not expect it as an argument of the selector and just pass it as parameter to `selectSingleMedia` like below:

```
  const {mediaId} = useParams();
  const media = useSelector((state) => selectSingleMedia(state, mediaId))
```

Comment: It didn't work. medias.media doesn't exist. I did change t he name of the slice to media tho. But it didn't matter

Comment: How do you apply this reducer to the store. I guess you have some code somewhere like `reducer: { media: mediaReducer }` ?

Comment: in the store.js
`export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    medias: mediasReducer,
    media: mediaReducer
  }
})`

Comment: Ok then you are right about `.media` . Then can you add on your description what's the value of the `loadedMedia`? Because in the `selectSingleMedia` you assume that `state.media.media` is an array, but i suspect it finally isn't.